# kubectl credential error on Gitlab runner

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, kubectl

I run `kubectl version` in Gitlab's CI with `gitlab-runner` user on build server. It fails on CI job but succeed on host's shell with same user.

I have this job in `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment: staging
  script:
    - whoami
    - kubectl version
```

It fails with the following error:

```
$ whoami
15 gitlab-runner
16 $ kubectl version
17 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
18 error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
22 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

`kubectl version` on the build server's shell using `gitlab-runner` user:

```
admin@BuildServer:~$ sudo -u gitlab-runner kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:13:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

It works fine in other projects CI jobs. It seems that build service in this project's CI job can't find the `/home/gitlab-runner/.kube/config`. But I think when the job runs with same `gitlab-runner` user, it should produce same result as running it locally with the same user.

What's the point I'm missing?

Comment: Try removing your kube config via Gitlab Dashboard and add a new one, it might fix. please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Because other project's CI works fine, I just cleared cluster and runner caches and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because other project's CI pipeline works fine with the same runner and issue was related to just one of my projects, I just used the **`Clear Runner Caches`** button on the pipelines page. (I also cleared cluster cache in the admin area, but I am not sure that was related to issue.)